# Getting the previous and next keys/values in array from current position (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, key

I have an array similar to the following:

```
const BookIndex = array
(
    '1' => 'Chapter 1',
    '1.1' => 'Chapter 1.1',
    '1.1.1' => 'Chapter 1.1.1',
    '2' => 'Chapter 2',
    '2.1' => 'Chapter 2.1',
    '2.1.1' => 'Chapter 2.1.1',
);
```

Let's say that I have determined somehow that the current key (position) I care about is the '2' key. How do I find the previous and next keys?

```
$CurrentKey = '2';
$CurrentValue = BookIndex[$CurrentKey];

$PreviousKey = null; // I need to figure out the previous key from the current key.
$PreviousValue = BookIndex[$PreviousKey];

$NextKey = null; // I need to figure out the next key from the current key.
$NextValue = BookIndex[$NextKey];
```

Comment: This is not terribly difficult. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried the current, prev and next functions but they don't work because the current function returns the first item in the array and not the starting point I chose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.prev.php) for that

```
$NextKey = next($BookIndex); // next key of array

$PreviousKey = prev($BookIndex); // previous key of array

$CurrentKey = current($BookIndex); // current key of array
```

pointing to specific position

```
$CurrentKey = '2';

while (key($BookIndex) !== $CurrentKey) next($BookIndex);
```

Comment: I know those functions exists, but current function returns the first item in the array and not an arbitrary key chosen by me.

Comment: You need to loop through array to set pointer on your desired position

Comment: How do I stop the loop, once I've found the key, in such a way that current() will then return that key, prev() the previous and next() the next?

Comment: Do prev() and next() loop around so that if current() is the last item in the array then next() moves to the first item in the array?

Comment: I just had a situation where the loop goes on forever, or until PHP kills it, when the value was not found.

Answer (score 0):

try this out.

```
   function get_next_key_array($array,$key){
        $keys = array_keys($array);
        $position = array_search($key, $keys);
        if (isset($keys[$position + 1])) {
            $nextKey = $keys[$position + 1];
        }
        return $nextKey;
    }

    function get_previous_key_array($array,$key){
        $keys = array_keys($array);
        $position = array_search($key, $keys);
        if (isset($keys[$position - 1])) {
            $previousKey = $keys[$position - 1];
        }
        return $previousKey;
    }


    $CurrentKey = '2';
    $CurrentValue = BookIndex[$CurrentKey];

    $PreviousKey = get_previous_key_array($BookIndex,$CurrentKey)
    $PreviousValue = BookIndex[$PreviousKey];

    $NextKey = get_next_key_array($BookIndex,$CurrentKey)
    $NextValue = BookIndex[$NextKey];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the previous answer, with the associative arrays, `next()` and `prev()` functions return the next or the previous value - not the key - regarding to your question.

Suppose that with your `$BookIndex` array. If you want to move and get the next value (or the previous), you can do like this:

```
$nextChapter = next($BookIndex); // The value will be 'Chapter 1.1'
$previousChapter = prev($nextChapter); // The value will be 'Chapter 1'
```

More, `next()` and `prev()` functions expect parameter to be `array`, not a `const`.