# How to get previous and next array value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, arraylist, php-curl

So I am using a RapidAPI's API where I am getting this below array after json_encode() it -

```
Array
(
    [00:00:00] => Array
        (
            [name] => Arr Name 1
            [other-details] => Arr Desscription 1
            [type] => Arr Type 1
        )

    [00:30:00] => Array
        (
            [name] => Arr Name 2
            [other-details] => Arr Desscription 2
            [type] => Arr Type 2
        )
)
```

Now that you have seen the structure I am getting from now on please notice that I am getting only the starting time I.e **[00:00:00]** and not the ending time i.e it should have been **[00:30:00]** the end time.

But using

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) { 
}
```

I am getting

- [00:00:00]
- [00:30:00]

respectively as you can expect in foreach I have tried using foreach inside foreach using array_slice but failed.

**So what I want is**

- Start Time - End Time
- **[00:00:00]  [00:30:00]**
- **[00:30:00]**     .....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the previous and next keys/values in array from current position (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46578113/getting-the-previous-and-next-keys-values-in-array-from-current-position-php)

Comment: ``array_chunk`` can help divide an array into ``2 items in a group``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take and loop the keys from the array using array_keys.

In the loop, print the starting time, and only print the ending time if it exist by checking if the key for the next value in the array exists.

```
$a = [
    '00:00:00' => [
        'name' => 'Arr Name 1',
        'other-details' => 'Arr Desscription 1',
        'type' => 'Arr Type 1'
    ],
    '00:00:30' => [
        'name' => 'Arr Name 2',
        'other-details' => 'Arr Desscription 2',
        'type' => 'Arr Type 2'
    ],
    '00:01:00' => [
        'name' => 'Arr Name 3',
        'other-details' => 'Arr Desscription 3',
        'type' => 'Arr Type 3'
    ],
    '00:01:30' => [
        'name' => 'Arr Name 4',
        'other-details' => 'Arr Desscription 4',
        'type' => 'Arr Type 4'
    ]
];

$keys = array_keys($a);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($keys); $i++) {
    $result = $keys[$i];
    if (array_key_exists($i+1, $keys)) {
        $result .= " " . $keys[$i + 1];
    }
    echo $result . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
00:00:00 00:00:30
00:00:30 00:01:00
00:01:00 00:01:30
00:01:30
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/s4u87)

Comment: Please could also share how to get the key along with the values like                            
   00:00:00 00:00:30  Arr Name 1 Arr Desc 1 Arr type 1

Comment: @web90 Do you mean like this? https://3v4l.org/mBGn9

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you're looking for:

```
<?php

// sample data
$data = [
    
    "00:00:00" => [
        "name" => "Test name",
        "details" => "Test details",
        "type" => "Test type"
    ],
    
    "00:30:00" => [
        "name" => "Test name",
        "details" => "Test details",
        "type" => "Test type"
    ],
    
    "00:60:00" => [
        "name" => "Test name",
        "details" => "Test details",
        "type" => "Test type"
    ]
    
];

$timeslots = [];

foreach(array_chunk($data, 2, TRUE) as $key => $value) {
    
    $timeslots[] = array_keys($value);
}

print_r($timeslots);

?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00:00:00
            [1] => 00:30:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 00:60:00
        )

)
```

Comment: Hmm, let me fix it. ☹️

Comment: Please add how to get all the values at the same time like - 00:00:00 00:00:30 Arr Name 1 Arr Desc 1 Arr type 1 .....